# SQL join two count selects

Tags: sql, select, join, sybase

I have two SQL selects.

First:

```
SELECT v.red_club, count(v.red_club) 
FROM v_round as v
GROUP BY v.red_club
```

and it is returning:

```
red_club   count(v.red_club) 
ABC        22
DEF        12
XYZ        4
```

Second select:

```
SELECT v.green_club, count(v.green_club) 
FROM v_round as v
GROUP BY v.green_club
```

and it is returning:

```
green_club   count(v.green_club) 
ABC        5
DEF        9
XYZ        33
```

How can I join the counts together (in one select), so that the result look like:

```
club   count(total) 
ABC        27
DEF        21
XYZ        37
```

Comment: If green_club is populated, does that mean that red_club is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried UNION-ing  the results of each query?

```
SELECT lbl, SUM(cnt)
FROM(
     SELECT v.red_club lbl, count(v.red_club)  cnt
     FROM v_round as v
     GROUP BY v.red_club
     UNION ALL
     SELECT v.green_club lbl, count(v.green_club) cnt
     FROM v_round as v
     GROUP BY v.green_club
)
Group by lbl
```

Comment: It would depend on the name of the groups. If Green and red clubs had the same names: 3 rows. If they are all distinct: 6. That is why we are grouping by lbl.
The UNION 'ALL' is used because SQL will removed dupe rows: If Green club had a name of A and had a count of 10 & the the red club had a name of A count of 10, SQL would return just 1 record, meaning your sums would be off.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    select red.red_club as club, rcount+gcount as cout 
from 
(
SELECT v.red_club, count(v.red_club) as rcount
FROM v_round as v
GROUP BY v.red_club
) as red 
inner join 
(
SELECT v.green_club, count(v.green_club) as gcount
FROM v_round as v
GROUP BY v.green_club
) as green on red.red_club = green.green_club
```